# VSCode hot reload for Flutter does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm on VSCode right now working on my flutter application when hot reload just stops working, right in the middle of my development. I have absolutely no idea why this happens, I had no issue with this before at all in the past. If it helps anyone, I'm working on the second page of my app, which you get to via a route on the first page. Is this why hot reload isn't working? If it isn't can someone tell me why it doesn't work? This is really annoying and hindering progress on my app. Thanks!

Restarting my computer, and restarting the debugging. I'm on a Macbook Pro 2015 running macOS Mojave Version 10.14.2 if that helps.

There isn't really any code to show, it's not code related. It's VSCode or Flutter.

I expect the hot reload to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Why don't you fill a bug on Github?

Comment: Is this serious enough to fill out an issue form? It seems like this is probably a minor issue and I haven’t seen others bring this up

Comment: Personally I use Android Studio, so can't tell much about this issue. Let's wait for someone else coming up with a solution.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: This happen also to me also, better you fill on bug on github. It start happen yesterday, seems after call 'flutter upgrade'.

Comment: Try to use `flutter clean` before compiling. Then try again the hot reload feature. Might fix your issue

Comment: Same issue, I'm debugging in iOS Simulator, so it can't be Android Studio problem, right?

Comment: Android Studio users watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiujjJxLGIk

Answer (score 52):

The hot reload doesn't work if you launch your app using f5 or select start debugging from the dropdown of debug .

But if you launch your app using Ctrl+f5 or select start without debugging from the dropdown of debug .

To solve the issue first close the running debugging session using Shift+f5.

Then click debug from the menu bar. Click Start without debugging.

[image: Start Without Debugging]

Now The Hot reload works perfectly fine.

You can do the hot reload also using terminal.
Just type: **flutter run** in the terminal and the app will be launched.

just press **r** in the terminal and **hot reload** will be initialized.

Comment: It did work for me - Sept 2021

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works - Oct 2021

Comment: Not working anymore, Feb 2022

Comment: On Mac, I discovered that I need to launch from VS Code (using Run > Start Debugging, or F5) rather than using 'Flutter run' in Terminal. Hot reload will not work when saving in VS Code if I start from Terminal.

Comment: No. Just type: flutter run in the terminal and the app will be launched. just press r in the terminal and hot reload will be initialized.
Not true for me when target device is real android device, in case of web or OS (linx in my case) it works.

Answer (score 52):

I have noticed that hot reload is not working if you in `runApp` directly pass in `MaterialApp`. If separate core widget is created than everything works properly.

**Working example:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hot reload works!!')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Not working:**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hot reload not working')),
  ),
));
```

Also don't forget to enable hot reload on save: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67132314/4990406

Comment: See @moaaz.m.f's answer above for details on enabling hot reload on save in vscode

Comment: @LelandReardon The problem here is because the "main" function runs only once and the hot reload doesn't run the main function or something else because hot reloading was enabled in both examples

Comment: Agreed, and your answer worked for me :) Hot reloading apparently doesn't rerun main. Just wanted to reference the above tip, as I found it useful in combination with your solution.

Answer (score 29):

if you are still facing this issue

open VS code then go to:

- File > Preferences > Settings
- in the search field type "Hot Reload"
- you will see "Flutter Hot Reload On Save" and options are there
- the default is "manual" so change it to "all" or "allIfDirty"

Update - 12/Jun/2022 : instead of "always" the option now is = "All"

Comment: This was it, thank you! Seems like `allIfDirty` is the option you'd want to set, I wonder why it's not the default.

Answer (score 9):

For VS Code
Go to File>Autosave
Make sure you have "check" Autosave.

Comment: This helped me. (Y)

Comment: helped me too, but it is unncessarily reloading all the time code changes

Answer (score 8):

Quoting here the answer of [sidnas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990406/sidnas)

> I have noticed that hot reload is not working if you in runApp
> directly pass in MaterialApp. If separate core widget is created than
> everything works properly.
>
> Working example:
>
> ```
> void main() => runApp(MyApp());
>
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>       home: Scaffold(
>         appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hot reload works!!')),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Not working:
>
> ```
> void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
>   home: Scaffold(
>     appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hot reload not working')),
>   ),
> ));
> ```

The reason why the second snippet prevents the hot reload from working is because the "main" only runs once and the hot reload doesn't run the main. So to make it work, you have to separate the MaterialApp to a different widget.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear on why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

For me on the latest VS studio, pressing CRTL+s does the hot reload nicely for me.
kinda a habbit from other IDE's.

Comment: Also, a note i dont bother using the cmd

Comment: Why does this work ? I was repeatedly pressing CTRL + F5 and clicking the hot reload button.

Comment: i wish i could tell you, i havnt been using flutter for awhile as i've been tied up with other work. 
if i were to make an educated guess some IDE's wont build the current build till you save it, usually denoted with an astrix on the top corner of the tab you're working on.

so once you save it, it may automatically compile and build it, but im also guessing these a wacky bug in the mix as i did initially try what they suggested and it didnt work

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to force the hot reload in VS Code, which is very useful for those stuck in this situation: after the application is running, simply click on the debug option at the bottom of the VS Code editor whem the button is already named "Flutter" and, after choosing "flutter" again at the "Debug Configuraion" top floating window, you will be notified that the application is already being debugged, but the hot reload will occur.

Answer (score 2):

If you're implementing your MaterialApp in main.dart will cause this issue, the best practice is to separate out another dart file, then refer from main.dart.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a vscode issue in version 1.32.1 - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29275 and https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1518

In the meantime, you could revert to 1.31, wait for a fix in the next version, install the insiders version (which includes a fix), or could use 'flutter run' from the vscode terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the official documented cases where hot reload wont work:

1. Data regarding the sate of the app is changed (since Flutter tries to maintain the state of your app between hot reloads)
2. Change in global variables or static field since Flutter regards them as state
3. Changes to anything that are not in the build path (eg. initState()) and also the app's main itself
4. You've got compilation errors, check `debug console` to be sure
5. App is killed either by user or by OS because of inactivity
6. When Enumerated types are changed to to regular classes or vise versa
7. Font is changed
8. When Generic type decorations are modified
9. When included native code (Java, Kotlin or Swift) is modified
10. CupertinoTabView builder widget

reference: [Hot Reload](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload)

Answer (score 1):

first save your project then hot reload it.

Answer (score 1):

Work for me:

1. Go to the flutter directory on your pc.
2. Write to the console: git checkout tags/2.0.5
   (2.0.5 is latest version in stable tree for now, you can choose any others.)
3. Write to the console in your project: flutter --version
   And hot reload should work.
   I don't know why, but after command: flutter upgrade, my hot reload don't work

Answer (score 1):

Try the following things

1. Make sure auto-save is checked under file
2. Go to settings and make sure that flutter auto load isn't manual. Change it to all if it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Currently I am using VSCode version 1.39.2.

For the hot reload to work you need to start debugging in VSCode.

As it says in the docs: "Only Flutter apps in debug mode can be hot reloaded."
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload

You can find that option on the VSCode's top navigation inside Debug or with the shortcut F5.

You don't need to do flutter run on your terminal, nor even on VSCode, is just start debugging and it will launch lib/main.dart in debug mode.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try downgrading to the last version of VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

with VS Code(v1.44.1), Android Studio(v3.6.2), Flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.9 on Linux

Android studio > at Startup window > configure > AVD manager > run one virtual device > confirm VS Code(v1.44.1) has your running virtual device shown in lower right corner

VS Code > Run(at top, next to Help) > Start debugging(F5) or Start without debugging(Ctrl + F5)

Save your Flutter code in VS Code
Then the emulator should be triggered for hot reload

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using MAC.

I am using mac, and I handled this through by quitting first the emulator and VS Code and then restarting the computer.

It should be kept in mind that when you use stateless or stateful widget then you can get the feature of hot reload.

By pressing command+s it will save the file and will perform hot reload automatically.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have changed the Keyboard shortcuts for hot reloading , kindly check if it is...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30017915)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** is :

1. Click on `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings`
2. Search for "Hot Reload"
3. Click on `Flutter Hot Reload On Save` and choose `always`
4. after that Click on `File` and Click on `Autosave`.

Answer (score 0):

try killing dart from terminal
by typing `killall -9 dart`

then:
1- close vscode

2- re-open vscode (it may crash in the first run so reopen it again)

3- run `flutter clean`

4- run `flutter pub get`

5- run `flutter run`

this will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code: File > Auto Save
Auto save can solve this problem. When I used Ctrl+F5, I saw in vs code that it works, but nothings changed on the screen of emulator. I click on the File and then Auto save. After that my problem was solved. I tried the other solutions that other people wrote, but they didn't work for me. Only one person said it. Thanks him.

Answer (score 0):

## Open your Visual Studio Code then go to:

#### File > Preferences > Settings > In Search type Hot Reload > In Flutter Hot Reload > Change default-Manual to > Always or All.

Answer (score -1):

For flutter **hot reload** **problems** that may be happening with your project,

It is a problem with your **device**, and not **flutter** or **Android Studio**

This happens when your **logcat** **hangs up**.

You might want to **increase** your **buffer size**.

To do this, go into your **device** or **emulator**:

**Settings > Developer options** (*Ensure they are turned on*),

Change the buffer size to a higher number.

Then run **flutter run -v** again

Comment: same issue happening for me also and no success with above steps.

Comment: This is copy pasted from a GH issue!? I just read that somewhere else and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in VS code. Here is how I solved it :

1. I was using `style` property for `Text` from an external file. I found that change in external file doesn't reflect in hot reload.

   ```
             Text(
               AppStrings.giveFeedbackPageText,
               style: AppStyles.bodyText,
               textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
             ),
   ```

   So I had to use `TextStyle` from that file instead of an external file, and it works! Dont know the reason. Probably the external `style` needs to be inside a widget.
2. Another solution could be - separating `home` from `MaterialApp` into a separate widget.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you don't have this type of imports I was going crazy and deleting them fixed the hot reload, check all your files, I found this answer in github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49744

import file:///C:/Users/.../.../< App Name >/lib/filename.dart

Answer (score -3):

try Ctrl + S ,
when I press Ctrl + S it's automatically doing hot reload