# How can i get back hot reload feature?

Tags: flutter

I'm running flutter on terminal. My flutter hot reload is missing and I’m getting an error as given below.

```
log: Must be admin to run 'stream' command 
Script started, output file is /dev/null
Script done, output file is /dev/null
```

I changed my channel to master and it still did not work.

Comment: what error, please post some code?

Comment: Perhaps you need to update VSCode

Comment: why not try to re download flutter?

Comment: i did redownload flutter. and did not work

Comment: What is the IDE or Editor you are using? If it is IntelliJ or Android Studio, there is hot reload feature that you can enable or disable in setting. If it is VS Code, you get Dart code package installed with Flutter that provide hot reload, run and with outher things. So, check on Dart Code if it is VS Code

Comment: You're missing your hot reload feature because of the recent bug in the February release (version 1.32). Downgrading to 1.31 helped me (Assuming you're using vscode)  I'm not sure about the admin error though.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284047/vscode-hot-reload-for-flutter-does-not-work

Comment: I got the Hot reload by becoming admin on my mac