# Hot reload function in flutter stopped working in VS code

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter hot reload shortcut options stopped working even after restarting the machine.
Below is the console log. Any idea how to fix this?
This was working fine till last week. Yesterday I was using vs code for doing a grunt build. Then I close the application. When I opened my android app it stopped working.

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 1 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 2 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 3 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 4 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 5 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 6 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 7 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 8 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 9 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 10 tries
I/flutter (17530): Observatory server failed to start after 11 tries
I/flutter (17530): Could not start Observatory HTTP server:
I/flutter (17530): SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 0
I/flutter (17530): #0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:774:7)
I/flutter (17530): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (17530): #1      _RawServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1458:26)
I/flutter (17530): #2      _ServerSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1729:29)
I/flutter (17530): #3      ServerSocket._bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1720:26)
I/flutter (17530): #4      ServerSocket.bind (dart:io/socket.dart:386:27)
I/flutter (17530): #5      _HttpServer.bind (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2838:25)
I/flutter (17530): #6      HttpServer.bind (dart:_http:228:19)
I/flutter (17530): #7      Server.startup.poll (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart:428:36)
I/flutter (17530): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (17530): #8      Server.startup.poll (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart)
I/flutter (17530): #9      Server.startup (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart:440:23)
I/flutter (17530): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (17530): #10     main (dart:vmservice_io:284:13)
```

Comment: I referred the below thread as well. but no luck..

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2138

Comment: This question is already answered. Please see this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284047/vscode-hot-reload-for-flutter-does-not-work#:~:text=The%20hot%20reload%20doesn%27t,debugging%20session%20using%20Shift%2Bf5.