# How to get Flutter's Hot Reload to work on VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, hot-reload, flutter-hotreload

I cannot get Hot Reload to work on VS Code. I'm using the drop down menu to "Run without Debugging" (although the problem persists even if I "Start Debugging").

When I press Hot Reload, it shows a success message but the changes are not reflected on the app.

Hot Restart is working perfectly fine.

How do I fix this?

I've tried:

1. Moving the MaterialApp from main() to another widget.
2. Making sure the changes I'm testing for are within the build function.
3. Restarting my computer and VSCode.

Comment: The issue went away. I don't why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- A similar Q&A has been posted before: [VSCode hot reload for Flutter does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284047/vscode-hot-reload-for-flutter-does-not-work)
- Follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSefeyF_IRQ
- Check the Flutter Documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/vs-code

  [image]
- At the menu at the top of VS Code, go to File and set the check mark for Auto Save

Comment: I tried all of them. None of them had worked.